# how to locate the shell script file of a process

Tags: shell

Suppose I saw a process X in output of top or ps, I want to know which shell script started it, is there a easy way?
I think it's too stupid to find/grep the whole harddisk.

EDIT: I just want to find the script file name and path, not the command line which start the process.

Answer (score 1):

In ps, there is the ability to view ppid, the parent process id.   That will indicate the process that started the child.   For a prettier display, check out pstree.